# How do I convert a Julian date stored as a double-precision value to a timestamp with at least one-minute resolution?

Tags: postgresql

I exported data from an SQLite table to a CSV file.  The data includes a timestamp with at least one-minute resolution:  "2019-11-15 01:30:06".  The data is actually stored as a Julian date, in this case 2458802.35424295.  I imported the data into a double-precision field.  I need to convert that number into a timestamp with time zone.  I tried casting the double-precision number to text and then using to_timestamp(), but that appears to work only with integer days.  I can get a timestamp, but it is always at midnight of the correct date.  I tried using to_timestamp() passing in my number, but that returns an epoch (number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970).

I could try to take the fractional part of my Julian date value, calculate the number of milliseconds since midnight that represents, use the to_timestamp(text,text) method to get the date I need, and then add the epoch since midnight to that date.  But that's awfully cumbersome.  Isn't there a better way?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.

NOTE:  The simple answer to my problem, which occured to me just before I clicked the Post button, is to export the data in the form I want, using SQLite's datetime() function to convert the number to a date string during export.  But I remain curious.  I would have thought there would be a standard way to do this conversion.

Comment: I don't think that there is a better way than splitting off the fractional days and translating them separately.

Comment: Strange.  Thanks for your reply.